# Hostname connectivity problem (nslookup/ping)

Tags: windows

I am trying to connect with Windows Remote Desktop to a server in our local network. However RDP does not know the hostname. I started to troubleshoot with powershell to see what's going on.

1. first I try to ping the server by name => could not find host
2. then I do a nslookup to see if I have any dns record => yes (name/address pair in nslookup).
3. then I ping using the ip I got from nslookup => works
4. then I try to use the ip in RDP => works

The process is attached.[image: ps]

I also tried an ipconfig /flushdns which does absolutely nothing in this case. Can someone please give me some pointers why I cannot connect using the hostname? I cannot properly search for pointers online if I have no keywords to look for.